# How to get the old value in a textbox before I submit it in angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I want to get the old value in a textbox and save it in a temporary variable where I can use it if I click a cancel/reset button

part of the client.html

```
<input type="text" id="txtage" placeholder="Age" data-ng-model="vm.client.age" />
<button type="submit" data-ng-click="cancel()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
```

client.js file

```
var vm = this;
vm.clients = [];
vm.client = {
        id: '',
        age: ''
    };
vm.cancel = cancel;  
 function cancel() {
        clientService.cancel(vm.client);
        getClients();
    }
function getClients() {
        vm.clients = clientService.get();
    }
```

clientService.js

```
 function cancel(client) {

        newValue[] = clients;
        cancel_lagi = function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
        clients.new = 'New Value :' + clients.newValue;
        clients.old = 'Old Value :' + $scopes.oldValue;
        clients.oldvalue = oldvalue;
        client.newValue = oldvalue;
        }
    }
```

if i click a data from the table and try to change its values in a textfield. After changing it I might change my mind so when I click the cancel button it will return to its old value.

when I click the cancel button the fields that I try to edit will return to its old value.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce another variable to keep track of the old value when edit is clicked. Then in cancel you can reset the value. In pseudocode:

```
editClicked(client) {
   vm.client = angular.copy(client);
   vm.originalClient = client;
}

cancelClicked() {
    vm.client = vm.originalClient;
    vm.originalClient = null;
}
```